# Play multiple sounds with same timestamp

Tags: python, audio

I am writing an AB listenning test app that can play multiple audio files with a shared timestamp. Say I have two audio files loaded which have the same length, when I start to play sound, I click a button to switch between these two files every several seconds and I want to preserve the timestamp to continue playing another file.

The key is to return the current frame number (timestamp) of played audio stream, and then start playing another file from this frame.

I'm trying to use `simpleaudio` to achieve this goal but it seems cannot return the current frame. Another approach is to measure the time during this file's playback (between timespan of two clicks) using `datetime` and calculate the new start index myself, but I think there must be some better way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `PyQt5` to create your App, `PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer` can do this.

```py
player = QMediaPlayer() # create a player object

player.pause() # pause
position = self.player.position() # save current playing timestamp
player.setMedia(content) # switch to another content
player.setPosition(position) # reset playing position
player.play() # continue to play
```